# UILabel with a link and a UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UILabel` with text and a link. The link is only part of the text and not all of it, however, its location in the text can change.

I've used `TTTAttributedLabel` for detecting the link, now I would like to add a gesture recognizer on the rest of the text which is not a link. Since, the link location can change I'm not sure how that would be possible to do.

Is this possible without external libraries?

Comment: Do you tried using any pod, like [ActiveLabel.swift](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift) or [LinkLabel](https://cocoapods.org/pods/LinkLabel)?

Comment: Thank you @Macabeus, I'm actually trying to find a native solution for this.

Comment: You said: "Add a gesture recognised on text that is **not link**". Are you sure? It seems weird. Just clarifying.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for clarifying @paper1111.

Comment: @Forge does your issue got fixed

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.textLabel.text = "Try to open https://www.google.com"
let text = self.textLabel.text
let sep = text?.components(separatedBy: " ")
for i in sep! {
    if isURL(string: i) {
        canopen.append(i)
    }
}
```

An extension for easier handling of label-tapping:

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapText(in label: UILabel, range targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: label.text!)
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configuration must be the same as the label!
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
    }

}
```

Then place a helper function to determine if it is an url:

```
func isURL(string: String?) -> Bool {
    guard let urlString = string else {return false}
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return false}
    if !UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {return false}

    let regEx = "((https|http)://)((\\w|-)+)(([.]|[/])((\\w|-)+))+"
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", argumentArray:[regEx])
    return predicate.evaluate(with: string)
}
```

And this is what to put in the `@IBAction` of your gesture, where the parameter of the `IBAction` is a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, not `Any?`:

```
let text = self.textLabel.text

for i in canopen {
    if sender.didTapText(in: textLabel, range: (text! as NSString).range(of: i)) {
        print("Tapped on a link, so do nothing")
        return
    }
}

print("Did not tap on a link, so do something")
<#code#>
```

Reference: http://samwize.com/2016/03/04/how-to-create-multiple-tappable-links-in-a-uilabel/

Answer (score 0):

If the  Usage of UIlabel is not compulsory. You can use UITextview that can detect links as well as you can click on that link too.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    urllbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 230, 240, 23)];
    urllbl.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    urllbl.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];

    urllbl.text = @"urlLink";
    urllbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap)];
    [urllbl addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [self.view addSubview:urllbl];
}

    -(void)labelTap
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.kyivpost.com"];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

}
 add this code, it will work  @Forge
```